# Database Conection C# ExecuteNonReader with MySql

Tags: c#, mysql

I have some issue's, ive seen a peace of code on the internet only this whas done with `Oledb`.

Now i have rewrited the code for MySQL.data.mysqlclient as followed:

```
MySqlDataReader dr = null;
        MySqlCommand cmd = null;
        string cmdstr = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='"+UsrName.Text+"' and password='"+PassWrd.Text+"' LIMIT 1";
        dr = cmd.ExecuteNonReader();
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdstr, connection);
        cmd.Dispose();

        if (dr.Read() == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Succesvol ingelogd");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Geen juiste gegevens");
        }
        connection.Close();

    }
```

Now the problem is another method for `dr = cmd.ExecuteNonReader()`.

UPDATE----------------

```
string server;
        string database;
        string uid;
        string password;
        server = "localhost";
        database = "cmstt";
        uid = "root";
        password = "";
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
        database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

        connection.Open();

        MySqlDataReader dr = null;
        MySqlCommand cmd = null;
        string cmdstr = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='"+UsrName.Text+"' and pass='"+PassWrd.Text+"' LIMIT 1";
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdstr, connection);


        if (dr.Read() == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Succesvol ingelogd");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Geen juiste gegevens");
        }
        cmd.Dispose();
        connection.Close();
```

Comment: Your code clearly open to SQL Injection. Please use parameterized SQL like `cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", email);`

Comment: Oh yeah, Little Bobby tables. http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png

Answer (score 2):

It will be `ExecuteReader()` not `ExecuteNonReader()`

// mention your connection and connection string here.

```
        connection.open()

        SqlDataReader dr = null;
        MySqlCommand cmd = null;
        string cmdstr = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='"+UsrName.Text+"' and password='"+PassWrd.Text+"' LIMIT 1";

        cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdstr, connection);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read() == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Succesvol ingelogd");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Geen juiste gegevens");
        }
        connection.Close();

    }
```

Comment: dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
nullReferenceException was unhandled :
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: make sure you have open connection of sql server.

Answer (score 0):

You are disposing cmd prematurely. Dispose it just before you close the connection.

Comment: connection is open and cmd is desposed before connection close.
Still have the error